# Retrieve email from gmail server using pop3 in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Class Pop3
    Inherits Sockets.TcpClient
    Dim Stream As Sockets.NetworkStream
    Dim UsesSSL As Boolean = False
    Dim SslStream As Security.SslStream
    Dim SslStreamDisposed As Boolean = False
    Public LastLineRead As String = vbNullString
    Public Overloads Sub Connect(ByVal server As String, _
                             ByVal username As String, _
                             ByVal password As String, _
                             Optional ByVal inport As Integer = 110, _
                             Optional ByVal usessl As Boolean = False)
        If Connected Then disconnect()
        UsesSSL = usessl
        MyBase.Connect(server, inport)
        Stream = MyBase.GetStream()
        If UsesSSL Then
            SslStream = New Security.SslStream(Stream)
            SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(server)
        End If
        If Not checkresponse() Then Exit Sub
        If CBool(Len(username)) Then
            Me.Submit("user" & username & vbCrLf)
            If Not checkresponse() Then Exit Sub
        End If
        If CBool(Len(password)) Then
            Me.Submit("pass" & password & vbCrLf)
            If Not checkresponse() Then Exit Sub
        End If
    End Sub
    Public Function checkresponse() As Boolean
        If Not IsConnected() Then Return False
        LastLineRead = Me.Response
        If (Left(LastLineRead, 3) <> "+ok") Then
            Throw New POP3Exception(LastLineRead)
            Return False
        End If

        Return True
    End Function
    Public Function IsConnected() As Boolean
        If Not Connected Then
            Throw New POP3Exception("Not Connected to an Pop3 Server")
            Return False
        End If
        Return True


    End Function
    Public Function Response(Optional ByVal datasize As Integer = 1) As String
        Dim enc As New ASCIIEncoding
        Dim serverbufr() As Byte
        Dim index As Integer = 0
        If datasize > 1 Then
            ReDim serverbufr(datasize - 1)
            Dim dtsz As Integer = datasize
            Dim sz As Integer
            Do While index < datasize
                If UsesSSL Then
                    sz = SslStream.Read(serverbufr, index, dtsz)
                Else
                    sz = Stream.Read(serverbufr, index, dtsz)
                End If
                If sz = 0 Then Return vbNullString
                index += sz
                dtsz -= sz
            Loop
        Else
            ReDim serverbufr(255)
            Do
                If UsesSSL Then
                    serverbufr(index) = CByte(SslStream.ReadByte)
                Else
                    serverbufr(index) = CByte(Stream.ReadByte)
                End If
                If serverbufr(index) = -1 Then Exit Do
                index += 1
                If serverbufr(index - 1) = 10 Then Exit Do
                If index > UBound(serverbufr) Then
                    ReDim Preserve serverbufr(index + 256)

                End If
            Loop
        End If
        Return enc.GetString(serverbufr, 0, index)

    End Function

    Public Sub Submit(ByVal message As String)
        Dim enc As New ASCIIEncoding
        Dim WriteBuffer() As Byte = enc.GetBytes(message)
        If UsesSSL Then
            SslStream.Write(WriteBuffer, 0, WriteBuffer.Length)
        Else
            Stream.Write(WriteBuffer, 0, WriteBuffer.Length)
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub disconnect()
        Me.Submit("QUIT" & vbCrLf)
        checkresponse()
        If UsesSSL Then
            SslStream.Dispose()
            SslStreamDisposed = True
        End If

    End Sub
    Public Function statistics() As Integer()
        If Not IsConnected() Then Return Nothing
        Me.Submit("STAT" & vbCrLf)
        LastLineRead = Me.Response
        If (Left(LastLineRead, 3) <> "+OK") Then
            Throw New POP3Exception(LastLineRead)
            Return Nothing
        End If
        Dim msgInfo() As String = Split(LastLineRead, " "c)
        Dim result(1) As Integer
        result(0) = Integer.Parse(msgInfo(1))
        result(1) = Integer.Parse(msgInfo(2))
        Return result

    End Function

    Public Function List() As ArrayList
        If Not IsConnected() Then Return Nothing
        Me.Submit("LIST" & vbCrLf)
        If Not checkresponse() Then Return Nothing

        Dim retval As New ArrayList
        Do
            Dim response As String = Me.Response
            If (response = "." & vbCrLf) Then
                Exit Do
            End If
            Dim msg As New Pop3Message
            Dim msgInfo() As String = Split(response, " "c)
            msg.number = Integer.Parse(msgInfo(0))
            msg.bytes = Integer.Parse(msgInfo(1))
            msg.Retrieved = False
            retval.Add(msg)
        Loop
        Return retval
    End Function

    Public Function GetHeader(ByRef msg As Pop3Message, Optional ByVal BodyLines As Integer = 0) As Pop3Message
        If Not IsConnected() Then Return Nothing
        Me.Submit("TOP " & msg.number.ToString & " " & BodyLines.ToString & vbCrLf)
        If Not checkresponse() Then Return Nothing
        msg.Message = vbNullString

        Do
            Dim response As String = Me.Response
            If response = "." & vbCrLf Then
                Exit Do
            End If
            msg.Message &= response
        Loop
        Return msg

    End Function
    Public Function Retrieve(ByRef msg As Pop3Message) As Pop3Message
        If Not IsConnected() Then Return Nothing
        Me.Submit("RETR " & msg.number.ToString & vbCrLf)
        If Not checkresponse() Then Return Nothing
        msg.Message = Me.Response(msg.bytes)

        Do
            Dim S As String = Response()
            If S = "." & vbCrLf Then
                Exit Do
            End If
            msg.Message &= S
        Loop
        msg.bytes = Len(msg.Message)
        Return msg
    End Function

    Public Sub Delete(ByVal msgHdr As Pop3Message)
        If Not IsConnected() Then Exit Sub
        Me.Submit("DELE " & msgHdr.number.ToString & vbCrLf)
        checkresponse()
    End Sub
    Public Sub reset()
        If Not IsConnected() Then Exit Sub
        Me.Submit("RSET" & vbCrLf)
        checkresponse()

    End Sub
    Public Function noop() As Boolean
        If Not IsConnected() Then Return False
        Me.Submit("NOOP")
        Return checkresponse()
    End Function

    Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
        If SslStream IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not SslStreamDisposed Then
            SslStream.Dispose()
        End If
        MyBase.Finalize()

    End Sub
    Public Function ReadPop3(ByVal Server As String, _
                              ByVal username As String, _
                              ByVal password As String, _
                              Optional ByVal Inport As Integer = 110, _
                              Optional ByVal usessl As Boolean = False) As ArrayList
        Try
            Dim inmail As New Pop3
            inmail.Connect(Server, username, password, Inport, usessl)
            Dim stats() As Integer = inmail.statistics()
            If stats(0) = 0 Then
                Return Nothing

            End If
            Dim locallist As New ArrayList
            For Each msg As Pop3Message In inmail.List
                locallist.Add(inmail.Retrieve(msg))
            Next
            inmail.disconnect()
            Return locallist
        Catch ex As POP3Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly Or MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error Encounted")

        Catch e As Exception
            MsgBox(e.Message, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly Or MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error Encounted")
        End Try
        Return Nothing
    End Function

End Class
Public Class Pop3Message
    Public MailID As Integer = 0
    Public ByteCount As Integer = 0
    Public number As Integer = 0
    Public bytes As Integer = 0
    Public Retrieved As Boolean = False
    Public Message As String = vbNullString

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Message
    End Function
End Class

Public Class POP3Exception
    Inherits ApplicationException

    Public Sub New(ByVal str As String)
        MyBase.New(str)
    End Sub
End Class

.................................................

 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Me.Button1.Enabled = False
        Dim emailbag As ArrayList = getmail.ReadPop3("Pop.gmail.com", "snshanjava@gmail.com", "shan1986", 995, True)
        If emailbag IsNot Nothing AndAlso emailbag.Count <> 0 Then
            For Each msg As Pop3Message In emailbag
                Me.TextBox1.Text = msg.Message
                MsgBox(msg.Message, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "message #" & msg.MailID.ToString & " of " & emailbag.Count.ToString)

            Next
        Else
            MsgBox("no Email found on server ", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly Or MsgBoxStyle.Information, "No email")
        End If

        Me.Button1.Enabled = True


    End Sub
```

her i want to get mail from gmail server using pop3 if mail found then display each  email stuff in textbox and display each message in messagebox but while debugging no errors there was exception ---exception of type 'test application' pop3 exception was thrown.Myproblem is i have many emails in  my  gmailaccount but not able to retrieve those emails and click event will process else condition and  it show an message box that no emails found on server.

somebody help on this issue .thanks in advance

Comment: What's the message of exception?

Comment: exception of type 'test application' pop3 exception was thrown.

Comment: That's not the message. Wrap your getmail.ReadPop3 in a try/catch block and see what ex.Message contains. You can even look at your Locals window in Visual Studio

Comment: Thanks for your response jamby, Then why i did'nt get any email.i have many email in above specified gmail account if mail found means display each  email stuff in textbox and display each message in messagebox. but it will process else condition in click event that ----'No email found on server'

Comment: How to fix pop 3 server errors in our application.

Comment: Providing more information.

Comment: while retrieving  mail from gmail server i got an exception that pop3-side error how to overcome this exception.

Answer (score -2):

First off, if you bothered to read David Ross Goben's PDF document, since the code you have posted is 100% his (apart from the comments you have removed), you would have noticed that providers like GMail, Yahoo and Hotmail all require SSL.

Secondly, you can always send a message to David R Goben on his Gmail address (as listed in the PDF document you got with his .NetEMail classes), I am sure he will be happy to know about your problem and how you go about posting his code without crediting him.

Lastly, if you left in the code comments (as David R Goben had it originally) other members could understand the code better without thinking about it.

Getting back to your problem.

There is a chance that the messages on the GMail server is already flagged as "Read" which could mean that these messages will not show up when you do a POP3.list.

Best is to use the POP3.Statistics to see if there are in fact messages to be downloaded.

In the event that the POP3.List returns a list of messages, you can fetch messages based on the values in the list since the List holds the UID of each message.

Another option is to stop reading your mail and allow your program to do either a POP3.Statistics and / or POP3.List to determine if there are any messages on the server.

**Next time credit people for the time and effort they have put into providing you with code that you can use to your own benefit.